# Convert {reverse_related_entries} to relationships

Tags: relationships, child

I used "{reverse_related_entries}" before but after the upgrade (2.8.1) i like to use the new Relationships.

I found some stuff in the docs. But i can't figure out what i have to do when the relationship-field is into the ChildChannel:

**ParentChannel**

- title

**ChildChannel**

- title
- relationship_field (Relationship)

**Template for ChildChannel:**

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="ParentChannel"}
{title}
{relationship_field}{relationship_field:title}{/relationship_field}     
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

What i need is a menu like this:

- Product-Family (from ParentChannel)

  - Product 1 (from ChildChannel with Relationship to Product-Family)
  - Produkt 2 (from ChildChannel with Relationship to Product-Family)
  - Produkt 3 (from ChildChannel with Relationship to Product-Family)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `parents` tag pair ([docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/relationships.html#accessing-parents)), since your "child" products are actually the "parents" (because the relationship originated from their entries, not the other way around).

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="ParentChannel"}
    {title}
    {parents field="ChildChannelRelationshipField"}
        {parents:title}
    {/parents}     
{/exp:channel:entries}
```